# Azure service principal vs managed identity vs (enterprise) application

Tags: azure

I want to create some kind of service account that I use as an identity for the application like a web app. I also want to use the credentials of this identity on-premises for local testing. How do I do it in Azure? Or is it just not possible, so I need to create two things, a managed identity for the app and a separate service principal/enterprise app for local testing?

In GCP it is very simple to do, but in Azure it is way more complicated. When I create a managed identity that I can attach to an app service/web app then I do not have access to the credentials. In GCP I can download a service account json file containing the credentials.

Comment: I'd suggest using a Managed Identity on the app service and your own identity locally. The code should be the same.

Comment: On the other hand if you want it to be *exactly* the same method, you can create an App Registration and create a client secret that would go in your app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problem using followings (**the links below are the articles I wrote in my blog**):

- **Azure:**

  - [App Service Easy Auth](https://hovermind.com/azure-app-service/easy-auth) for apps hosted in App Service
  - or [AKS Pod-Managed Identity Addon](https://hovermind.com/azure-kubernetes-service/pod-identity#managed-pod-identity-add-on) for apps deployed to AKS
- **For local testing:**

  - Login to visual studio using your Azure Credential
  - Make sure you have required roles assigned
  - During debugging, Visual Studio will use your credentials to access Azure services i.e. [to fetch KeyVault secrets](https://hovermind.com/aspnet-core/secret-management#accessing-azure-keyvault)

Comment: @EricAya I did not know that -> updated the answer accordingly!